# Recursive number triangle

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm having trouble trying to get the correct numbers to be in the correct position, my idea seems to be correct but the printing is incorrect.

```
    static int plotTri1(int n, int i) {
    if (n > 0) {
        plotTri1(n - 1, n + i);
        i += n;
        for (; 0 < n; n--) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", (i--));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return n;
}
```

My current solution prints out the following:

```
Given n = 5 and i = 0
  15
  14 13
  12 11 10
  9  8  7  6
  5  4  3  2  1
```

The desired solution is:

```
Given n = 5 and i = 0
  1
  3  2
  6  5  4
  10  9  8  7
  15 14 13 12 11
```

Looking for help that will lead me to the desired solution

Answer (score 1):

why do you use recursive function?

```
static void plotTri2(int n) {
    int k=1 ;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d",  new Object[] {new Integer(k-j)} );
        }
        k+= i+2 ;
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

plotTri2(5) ;

Comment: ...... because they're trying to solve the problem using recursion.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which worked for me.  The basic idea is to print from the starting number in each row down the the last number in that row, recursively.

```
public static void triangle(int n, int num) {
    if (n == 0) return;
    triangle(n - 1, num - n);
    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (i > 0) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(num - i);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    triangle(5, 15);
}
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

How about having the previous call return something? Here's one idea:

```
static int[] f(int n){
    if (n == 0){
        int[] firstRange = new int[]{1,1};
        return firstRange;
    }

    int[] range = f(n - 1);

    for (int i=range[0]; i<=range[1]; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", i);
    }
    System.out.println();

    int[] nextRange = new int[]{range[1] + 1, 2 * range[1] - range[0] + 2};
    return nextRange;
}
```